# Density curves on multiple histograms sharing same y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I need to overlay normal density curves on 3 histograms sharing the same y-axis. The curves need to be separate for each histogram.

My dataframe (example):

```
height <- seq(140,189, length.out =  50)
weight <- seq(67,86, length.out = 50)
fev <- seq(71,91, length.out = 50)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(height, weight, fev))
```

I created the histograms for the data as:

```
library(ggplot)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
gather(key=Type, value=Value) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Value,fill=Type)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = 8, position="dodge")
```

I am now stuck at how to overlay normal density curves for the 3 variables (separate curve for each histogram) on the histograms that I have generated. I won't mind the final figure showing either count or density on the y-axis.

Any thoughts on how to proceed from here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @akrun, thanks, but the examples from your suggestion solve the problem for a single variable. That was not what I was looking for. What I was struggling with was a way to find the solution when there are multiple histograms sharing the same y-axis.

Comment: You need a `facet_grid`/`facet_wrap` ?

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent, if faceting can do it in a 1 X 3 form so that the geom_histogram() + geom_density() can share the same y-axis, that will be wonderful.

Comment: Is the problem already solved? If not, check my answer, but I feel like removing it, it seems to me to be a dupe of @akrun's second link.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I think the OP is right.  I didn't check the `gather` part.  Removed the link

Comment: Everyone, thanks for your responses. I was able to solve the problem. Sorry about replying late. @RuiBarradas, either of your suggestions would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the code in the question is almost right, the code below just uses the answer in the link provided by @akrun.

Note that I have commented out the call to `facet_wrap` by placing a comment char before the last plus sign.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key = Type, value = Value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Value, color = Type, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),
                 binwidth = 8, position = "dodge") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.25) #+
  facet_wrap(~ Type)
```